# how to combine the results Future[ Option[ T ] ] into Seq[ T ]

Tags: scala, sequence, future, scala-option

I have a method

```
 def readTree(id: String): Future[Option[CategoryTreeResponse]]
```

and a list of String `channels:List[String]`.

**How to iterate and combine all the results into a non Future Sequence ?** such as :

```
 def readAllTrees(): Seq[CategoryTreeResponse] =  ???
```

Possibly without blocking.

Coming form the imperative world, I'd do like this :

```
import scala.concurrent.duration._

def readTrees(): Seq[CategoryTreeResponse] = {
  val list = ListBuffer[CategoryTreeResponse]()
  for (id <- channels) {
    val tree = Await.result(readTree(id), 5.seconds)
    if (tree.isDefined) {
      list += tree.get
    }
  }
  list
}
```

Comment: Could u please show what have u tried

Comment: Anyway, it's not possible to remove the `Future` if it's async

Comment: @cchantep , good to know . My first instinct was to Init a List `list` 1) loop the Seq. 2) block with `Await.result()` . 3) append `Option[CategoryTreeResponse]` to `list` . Pure IP ( imperative programming)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do something like this

```
def readAllTrees(channels: List[String]): Future[Seq[CategoryTreeResponse]] = {
    Future.sequence(channels.map(readTree(_))).map(_.flatten)
}
```

I have changed the signature of readAllTrees to receive the list and return a Future of the Sequence.

If you want to access to the resulting sequence you will need to wait until is finished doing

```
 Await.result(readAllTrees(channels), Duration.Inf)
```

But this is not a very nice way to manage futures because it will lock the thread that calls Await.ready

Comment: Nonetheless using `Await` is rarely a good solution to manage `Future`, but using `.get` on `Option` is unsafe

Comment: ok, provided a safer way to access to the result, anyway as I noted, using Await.ready is not a good approach, I used it because there's no context enough to give a better solution

Comment: As I guessed the only way is to block with `Await.result`

Comment: @Mikel , another issue with your solution : when you block `Future Sequence` , the timeout is the total timeout equals to `size of Sequence * individual timeout`. I have circuit breaker in front. Which is better : wait for each Future or wait for all whole Sequence ?

Comment: if you wait for the composed Future all the tasks wil be executed concurrently and only one Thread will be blocked. If you wait for each Future you will either have to execute sequentially or have one thread blocked per Future. So I think it's clearly better to use the composed Future

Answer (score 1):

Future.sequence and Await.result should help. I agree with Mikel though, it is better to stay async as long as possible using map/flatMap/foreach etc methods of the Future class

```
scala> :paste
// Entering paste mode (ctrl-D to finish)

import scala.concurrent._
import scala.concurrent.duration._
import scala.concurrent.ExecutionContext.Implicits.global

case class CategoryTreeResponse()

val futureResults: List[Future[Option[CategoryTreeResponse]]] = List(
 Future.successful(Option(CategoryTreeResponse())), 
 Future.successful(Option(CategoryTreeResponse())), 
 Future.successful(None)
) 
val futureResult: Future[List[Option[CategoryTreeResponse]]] = Future.sequence(futureResults)
val allResults: List[Option[CategoryTreeResponse]] = Await.result(futureResult, Duration.Inf)
val nonEmptyResults: Seq[CategoryTreeResponse] = allResults.flatMap(_.toSeq)

// Exiting paste mode, now interpreting.

import scala.concurrent._
import scala.concurrent.duration._
import scala.concurrent.ExecutionContext.Implicits.global
defined class CategoryTreeResponse
futureResults: List[scala.concurrent.Future[Option[CategoryTreeResponse]]] = List(Future(Success(Some(CategoryTreeResponse()))), Future(Success(Some(CategoryTreeResponse()))), Future(Success(None)))
futureResult: scala.concurrent.Future[List[Option[CategoryTreeResponse]]] = Future(Success(List(Some(CategoryTreeResponse()), Some(CategoryTreeResponse()), None)))
allResults: List[Option[CategoryTreeResponse]] = List(Some(CategoryTreeResponse()), Some(CategoryTreeResponse()), None)
nonEmptyResults: Seq[CategoryTreeResponse] = List(CategoryTreeResponse(), CategoryTreeResponse())

scala>
```